# Overriding mark for a single test in PyTest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

There is a test file with a global marker for each stored test:

```
from pytest import mark

pytestmark = mark.unit
```

This works as expected and all of the tests from this file as marked as `unit`. However, I'd like to override the mark for a single test, so that it no longer has the `unit` marker.

When I use the decorator on the test function that I want to modify, instead of overriding the original marker, it contains both `unit` and the new `integration` markers:

```
@mark.integration
def test_integration():
    pass
```

I've checked the marker decorator sources and it seems that it calls `store_mark` and has no additional properties that would let me override existing test markers.

Are there any idiomatic solutions to override existing testing marks or should I just store the tests in a separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think there is built-in functionality for this. You have a few options:

Implement a plugin that gives you an `unmark` decorator. [Someone has already tried this](https://github.com/astraw38/pytest-unmark) but I haven’t tested it.

Or Put all of your `unit` tests in a class and decorate the class with the marker.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.unit
class TestUnits:
    def test1(self):
        pass

@pytest.mark.integration
def integration_test():
    pass
```

Comment: Separating the tests was something that I originally did to solve this issue, I just wondered if there's a built-in solution for this. I might experiment with `unmark` next time if a similar problem arises. Thanks.